# How to make non-transferable token on solana

Tags: solana, solana-program-library

I'm trying to deploy non-transferable token on solana. As explained in the document, I used token-program-2022 example with non-transferable extension.

```
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    SystemProgram,
    Transaction,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
    createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
    createInitializeMintInstruction,
    getMintLen,
    ExtensionType,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@solana/spl-token';

(async () => {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

    const payer = Keypair.generate();
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature: airdropSignature, ...(await connection.getLatestBlockhash()) });

    const mintAuthority = Keypair.generate();
    const decimals = 9;

    const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
    const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.NonTransferable]);
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mint,
            space: mintLen,
            lamports,
            programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(mint, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, decimals, mintAuthority.publicKey, null, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)
    );
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, mintKeypair], undefined);
})();
```

But my transaction failed with this logs.

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/user/Desktop/workspace/solana-nft-js-test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4825:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/user/Desktop/workspace/solana-nft-js-test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4784:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/user/Desktop/workspace/solana-nft-js-test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4772:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/user/Desktop/workspace/solana-nft-js-test/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21)
    at async /Users/user/Desktop/workspace/solana-nft-js-test/src/example.ts:87:3 {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: Invalid instruction',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 725 of 600000 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0xc'
  ]
}
```

I can't find the reason why the transaction failed. Is token-program-2022 deployed on the 'devnet' different from the program in spl git repository?